# React Hook Form require rules of Controller always triggering

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I started using `react-hook-form` to validate my inputs, but the require rule is always triggering even if I typer/enter something in the input field.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button, Form, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

const setErrorStyle = (name) => {
  return {
    borderColor: name ? "red" : "",
    boxShadow: name ? "0 0 1.5px 1px red" : ""
  };
};

const App = () => {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
      <Label for="commentNote" className="mr-sm-10">
        Note/Comment
      </Label>
      <Controller
        name="commentNote"
        control={control}
        defaultValue={comment}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field: { ref, onChange, ...field } }) => (
          <Input
            {...field}
            type="textarea"
            rows={5}
            id="commentNote"
            innerRef={ref}
            value={comment}
            onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
            aria-invalid={!!errors.commentNote}
            style={setErrorStyle(errors.commentNote)}
          />
        )}
      />
      {errors.commentNote && (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">
          required
        </span>
      )}
      <Button type="submit" color="primary" size="sm" className="w-auto">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the SandBox for testing: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-wind-6v2gp

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because you are overriding the state handling of the form. What you actually do is you maintain your own state this way. If you want `react-hook-form` to maintain the state you need to remove the `onChange` handling in the `Input` and the `useState` from your code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Button, Form, Label, Input } from "reactstrap";

const setErrorStyle = (name) => {
  return {
    borderColor: name ? "red" : "",
    boxShadow: name ? "0 0 1.5px 1px red" : ""
  };
};

const App = () => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const submitForm = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
      <Label for="commentNote" className="mr-sm-10">
        Note/Comment
      </Label>
      <Controller
        name="commentNote"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
          <Input
            {...field}
            type="textarea"
            rows={5}
            id="commentNote"
            innerRef={ref}
            aria-invalid={!!errors.commentNote}
            style={setErrorStyle(errors.commentNote)}
          />
        )}
      />
      {errors.commentNote && (
        <span style={{ color: "red" }} role="alert">
          required
        </span>
      )}
      <Button type="submit" color="primary" size="sm" className="w-auto">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can't I have both? What I have a default value? How can I show it and be able to edit?

Comment: You can set the default value to whatever you want it is not a problem. If you need to render the value on other place you can use the `watch` API from the form on a specific field: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

Comment: Looks like easier and cleaner to create my own form state management than use the react-hook-forms. Thanks